# Why do I have to write both 'read' and 'r' to write a file by using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop\Python\Python_coursera\Course 1 - Notebook Resources\resources\week-2\datasets\census.csv')
```

If I omit the 'r', I cannot read the csv file. Is it normal to write both 'read' and 'r'? Because the course tutorial I followed did not introduce it.

If I just do not code 'r', this message comes out

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Also, if I move this file to my desktop and try to read it, I cannot read it at all. Do I need other code for reading?

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv('Desktop\census.csv')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'census.csv'
```

Comment: You need to mention a double back slash ```\\``` instead of 1. A ```\U``` starts a Unicode escape and then you have ```s```, which is invalid character.

Answer (score 2):

The `r` preceding a string literal in Python indicates that it's a [raw string](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). This allows it to treat the backslashes (`\`) as literal backslashes, instead of Unicode escapes. This feature is commonly used to write regex patterns. It has nothing to do with reading. Very unfortunately, Windows chose to use `\` as their path separator. To write Windows literal paths in Python you can use a raw string as you've done. Alteratively, just write it using the regular `/` path separator (i.e. `'C:/Users/OneDrive/Desktop/Python/Python_coursera/Course 1 - Notebook Resources/resources/week-2/datasets/census.csv'`). This won't work for low-level system APIs, but Python will generally handle converting the path separator to a system-appropriate one for you.

As for why `'Desktop\census.csv'` didn't work:

1. It should be either `r'Desktop\census.csv'` or `'Desktop/census.csv'`
2. Your program's current directory is not the directory containing your `Desktop` directory, so the relative path is incorrect. To check what directory your Python program is running in, you can use the following code: `import os; os.getcwd()`

Comment: Thank you so much! The first question was definitely helpful for me to understand the logic. For the second question, I changed my route as, r'C:\Users\\Downloads\census.csv', and then it totally worked!!!!

Answer (score 0):

For the first case:
You need to mention a double back slash `\\` instead of 1. A `\U` starts a Unicode escape and then you have `s`, which is invalid character.

Secondly, in windows:
the **Desktop** is actually found in `C:` drive. In the file explorer, when you click on the desktop shortcut, and select properties, you will see that it belongs to `C:\Users\...`. In your case, it is `C:\Users\OneDrive\Desktop`.

Comment: Thank you so much! The first question was definitely helpful for me to understand the logic. For the second question, I changed my route as, r'C:\Users\\Downloads\census.csv', and then it totally worked!!!!